# Search does not find all files in the Standard Documents Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search, search-results

The search function of my website collection does not work or the following behaviour is a mystery to me.
In my standard document library I have saved many test files. These have all "test objekt" in the file name.

[image: documents]

If I now enter the keyword "test objekt" in the search box, only 2 files are displayed.

[image: search]

When I click on "Show more search results", it doesn't do any more... only these stupid two files are displayed.

[image: search2]

In the library settings I have activated the setting - Search "Should items from this document library be displayed in search results?" I also re-indexed the library a few days ago.

What is the reason why I do not get the others displayed? The search is useless at the moment...

Comment: Your keyword has a space, what happens when you just use 'test' or 'testobjekt'?

Comment: Try to use search rest api to check the properties returned from the search keyword(and check if duplicates). /_api/search/query?querytext='keyword'&trimduplicates=false

Comment: @TrevorSeward As you can see on the screenshot I only use the search term "test".